# Find x number of array elements closest to target

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with potentially 1000+ elements and i have a dynamic target number, i want to get the closest x number of elements to the target number. 
Example:

```
let targetNumber = 1000.0
let matches = 5

let array = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000,13000,14000,15000,16000,17000]
```

If x would be 5,I would need the result to be filtered like the following: `[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]`

And if target number would be 10000 i would need the result to be basically reversed, `[10000,9000,8000,7000,6000,5000]`

The array can be sorted or not. What would be the best and most efficient way to achieve this result using Swift?

Comment: Best performance would be using a heap data structure but you could just sort them by distance.

Comment: See https://www.raywenderlich.com/160631/swift-algorithm-club-heap-and-priority-queue-data-structure and use distance as the priority.

Comment: @Sulthan, thank you, i'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define some testing data. Let's have a function:

```
func getClosest(count: Int, from values: [Int], to targetNumber: Int) -> [Int]
```

and we will test with the following:

```
let array = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 10000, 11000, 12000, 13000, 14000, 15000, 16000, 17000]
print(getClosest(count: 5, from: array, to: 1000))
print(getClosest(count: 5, from: array, to: 10000))
```

A trivial implementation is to sort the array by distance to the target number and grab the first X values:

```
func getClosest(count: Int, from values: [Int], to targetNumber: Int) -> [Int] {
    let getDistance: (Int) -> Int = {
        return abs(targetNumber - $0)
    }

    return Array(
        values
        .sorted { getDistance($0) < getDistance($1) }
        .prefix(count)
    )
}
```

The performance won't be bad (`O(n * log(n))` complexity, the complexity of sorting) but it's not optimal.

To really get a good complexity, we need to use a specialized data structure called [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue). Priority queue is a name for an abstract data structure that stores elements and can always return the element with the lowest priority.

A naive implementation of such a structure would be:

```
struct PriorityQueue<Element, Priority: Comparable> {
    private var elements: [(element: Element, priority: Priority)] = []

    var isEmpty: Bool {
        return elements.isEmpty
    }

    var count: Int {
        return elements.count
    }

    mutating func insert(element: Element, priority: Priority) {
        elements.append((element: element, priority: priority))
        elements.sort { $0.priority < $1.priority }
    }

    mutating func peek() -> Element? {
        return elements.first?.element
    }

    mutating func pop() -> Element? {
        guard !isEmpty else {
            return nil
        }

        return elements.remove(at: 0).element
    }

    func getElements() -> [Element] {
        return Array(elements.map { $0.element })
    }
}
```

This will basically just keep an inner array sorted but note how the interface of a priority queue looks like.

Then we can implement our function this way:

```
func getClosest(count: Int, from values: [Int], to targetNumber: Int) -> [Int] {
    let getDistance: (Int) -> Int = {
        return abs(targetNumber - $0)
    }

    var queue = PriorityQueue<Int, Int>()

    for value in values {
        queue.insert(element: value, priority: -getDistance(value))
        if queue.count > count {
            _ = queue.pop()
        }
    }

    return queue.getElements()
}
```

Now, with a naive implementation of priority queue, this won't help the complexity at all but if we implement the priority queue better then it will work.

A priority queue is usually implemented using [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), or more specifically [Fibonacci heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap).

Implementing them is not complicated once you understand the algorithm but there are some implementations already there. See [Swift Algorithm Club: Heap and Priority Queue Data Structure](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160631/swift-algorithm-club-heap-and-priority-queue-data-structure) for an example.

Comment: Concise, pointed me toward the exact result i was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
let closestToTarget = array.filter { array.index(of: $0)! <= array.index(of: targetNumber)! && array.index(of: targetNumber)! - array.index(of: $0)! <= 5 }.reversed() as [Int]
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what i'm looking for and if the target number is 1000 like on the example above it would only return 1000. But thanks!

Comment: I only write the answer for the second condition because the first one wasn't clear. For example, what if the target number was 2000? Do want the result to be reversed too? Anyway, just add another condition for the target if it's less than x and modify my answer to get what you need.